# $addToSet with condition in MongoDB not working with strings

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to aggregate a list of ICD codes for the following document

```
_id: "5facde3f9dXXXXXXX208",
EmpID: "MC20XXXXXXXXXX",
Coverage: "EMERGENCY"
DateLocked: 1900-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
CreatedBy: "ELIGIBILITY"
PlanCode: "1XXXXXXXXXXX"
GeneratedFrom: "1"
LoaType: ""
OpType:" "
Members:
Company:
ClaimsSummary:
ClaimsInfo:
Loa:
LoaDiagnosis:
    0:
        RecId:  1800XXXXXX
        Claimno:16XXXXXXXX
        Loa_No: "3XXXXXXXXX"
        IcdCode :   "S06.0"
        Diagnosis   :   "INTRACRANIAL INJURY: Concussion"
        FinalDiagnosis  :   " "
        ForPayStatus    :   " "
        CreatedBy   :   ""
        DateCreated :   1900-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
        ApprovedBy  :   ""
        DateApproved    :   1900-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
        CancelledBy :   ""
        DateCancelled   :   1900-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
        ProcessedBy :   ""
        DateProcessed   :   1900-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
        GPBatchNo:  ""
        Coverage: "N"
        RelatedIcd: ""
        CronicIllness:
            IcdGroupCode: "S06"
            IcdGroupDesc:"INTRACRANIAL INJURY"
            ChronicIllnessTagging:"N"
    1:
        RecId:  1800XXXXX
        Claimno:16XXXXXXXX
        Loa_No: "3XXXXXXXXX"
        IcdCode :   "S00.0"
        Diagnosis   :   "SUPERFICIAL INJURY OF HEAD: Superficial injury of scalp"
        FinalDiagnosis  :   " "
        ForPayStatus    :   " "
        CreatedBy   :   ""
        DateCreated :   1900-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
        ApprovedBy  :   ""
        DateApproved    :   1900-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
        CancelledBy :   ""
        DateCancelled   :   1900-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
        ProcessedBy :   ""
        DateProcessed   :   1900-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
        GPBatchNo:  ""
        Coverage: "N"
        RelatedIcd: ""
        CronicIllness:
            IcdGroupCode: "S00"
            IcdGroupDesc:"SUPERFICIAL INJURY OF HEAD"
            ChronicIllnessTagging:"N"
LoaCpt:
LoaPhysician:
PhysicianBill:
```

The pipeline that I've done so far is:

```
[{$group: {
  _id: "$EmpID",
  LOS: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: { 
                    if: { $gt: [ { $divide: [ { $subtract: [ "$DischargeDate", "$AdmissionDate" ] }, 24*60*60*1000 ] }, 0 ] },
                    then: { $divide: [ { $subtract: [ "$DischargeDate", "$AdmissionDate" ] }, 24*60*60*1000 ] },
                    else: 0
                }
            } 
        },
 icds_chronic: { 
            $addToSet: { 
                $cond: { 
                  **  if: { $eq: [ "$LoaDiagnosis.CronicIllness.ChronicIllnessTagging", "Y" ] }, **
                    then: "$LoaDiagnosis.IcdCode",
                    else: "$$REMOVE"
                }
           }
        },
}}, {$sort: {
  LOS: -1
}}]
```

However, the condition within the addToSet does not work. I get an empty array as the result for icds_chronic. I believe the issue would be related to the character 'Y'. Any other pointers would be helpful. I'm running mongo version 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to know because there are missing fields etc. Basically, add `$unwind` to your pipeline.

```
[{$unwind:"$loaDiagnosis"}, 
{$group: {
  _id: "$EmpID",
  LOS: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: { 
                    if: { $gt: [ { $divide: [ { $subtract: [ "$DischargeDate", "$AdmissionDate" ] }, 24*60*60*1000 ] }, 0 ] },
                    then: { $divide: [ { $subtract: [ "$DischargeDate", "$AdmissionDate" ] }, 24*60*60*1000 ] },
                    else: 0
                }
            } 
        },
 icds_chronic: { 
            $addToSet: { 
                $cond: { 
                  **  if: { $eq: [ "$LoaDiagnosis.CronicIllness.ChronicIllnessTagging", "Y" ] }, **
                    then: "$LoaDiagnosis.IcdCode",
                    else: "$$REMOVE"
                }
           }
        },
}}, {$sort: {
  LOS: -1
}}]
```

If you dont want to see the empty array before`$sort`ing add this stage

`{$match:{    "icds_chronic":{$elemMatch:{ $exists:true } }}}`

[I wrote a simplified version to play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PZSvPfVkxNJ)